# trying to set page header and footer in excel (xml)

Tags: excel, xml, tags, schema, spreadsheet

I am trying to add header and footer parts on my page when exporting from html to xls, but when i opened generated xls file i don't see header and footer on the page

```
<xml>
  <x:ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
      <x:ExcelWorksheets>
          <x:ExcelWorksheet>
            <x:Selected/>
            <x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name>

            <x:WorksheetOptions>
                <x:PageSetup>         
                     <x:Layout x:Orientation="Portrait"/>         
                     <x:Header x:Data="&amp;CВЕХНИЙ" Data="&amp;CВЕХНИЙ" data="&amp;CВЕХНИЙ" x:data="&amp;CВЕХНИЙ" />
                    <x:PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.5" x:Right="0.5" x:Top="0.75"/>     
                    <x:headerFooter>
                    <x:oddHeader>&LTEST LEFT&CTEST CENTER&RTEST RIGHT </x:oddHeader>
                    <x:oddFooter>Страница &P</x:oddFooter>
                    </x:headerFooter>   
                </x:PageSetup>
                <x:Print>
                    <x:ValidPrinterInfo/>
                    <x:Scale>79</x:Scale>
                    <x:PaperSizeIndex>9</x:PaperSizeIndex>
                </x:Print>
                <x:DisplayGridlines/>
            </x:WorksheetOptions>

          </x:ExcelWorksheet>
      </x:ExcelWorksheets>
      <x:ProtectStructure>False</x:ProtectStructure>
      <x:ProtectWindows>False</x:ProtectWindows>
  </x:ExcelWorkbook>
</xml>
```